# Using nonce in OCSP stapling

Tags: ocsp

When using openssl in c to verify nonce in regular OCSP (non stapling) i use this:
OCSP_check_nonce(request, basic response).

if I want to validate nonce as a client in OCSP stapling, how do I do it since I don't have the request?

Is there a way to tell the server what nonce to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nonces make no sense in stapled OCSP responses. The idea behind OCSP Nonce is to instruct OCSP server to invalidate its own cache and generate/sign new response.

When web server uses OCSP stapling, server gets a response in advance and caches it. This is literally the same as querying OCSP server without nonce (with a chance to get cached response). Technically, OCSP without nonce and OCSP stapling mean dealing with cached information and is not compatible with nonce.

If you want to validate the certificate with nonce, you must ignore stapled OCSP response, create your own OCSP request (with nonce) and submit it to OCSP server.

Comment: Thank you very much